# Failed to apply plugin [id 'hot-code-reloading']

Tags: intershop

I got a failure during the build process.

Failed to apply plugin [id 'hot-code-reloading']
/home/.../.gradle/gradle.properties (No such file or directory)

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily fix this by just creating the file:

```
touch /home/.../.gradle/gradle.properties
```